# If and else if and else - javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I just started to study Javascript and I am struggling to solve if and else if usage. here is my code. The problem is it kept showing 'none' results at the end no matter what numbers are put. Can you explain it to me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var grades,scores;
    scores=prompt ('write your score to convert it to grades');
    if (scores>101)
    grades='high distinction';
    else if (scores>91)
    grades='distinction';
    else if (scores>81)
    grades='credit';
    else if (scores>71)
    grades='pass';
    else if (scores>61)
    grades='fail';
    else (scores<60)
    grades='none';
document.write ('your grade name is'+grades);

    </script>
```

Comment: the final else shouldnt have a criteria

Comment: `else (scores<60)` should either be `else` or `else if (scores<60)`

Comment: @CalebHyun The line `else (scores<60)` should be `else if (scores<60)`. As is, the following statement `grades='none';` is executed regardless of the value of `scores`.

Comment: I got that now, Thanks mast3rd3mon !

Comment: @mast3rd3mon If everyone post their answers at the same time, I really do not know how they could read each others answers.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt you posted your answer a good 2 minutes after the first 2 answers, being 3 seconds between them, so you wouldve had time to read them

Answer (score 4):

The result of a `prompt` is always a string. Convert it to a number first to be safe:

```
scores = Number(prompt('write your score to convert it to grades'));
```

Also, your code here:

```
else(scores < 60)
grades = 'none';
```

`else` does not accept conditions like that. Either use else-if:

```
else if (scores < 60) grades = 'none';
```

or just `else`:

```
else grades = 'none';
```

In full:

```js
var grades, scores;
scores = Number(prompt('write your score to convert it to grades'));
if (scores > 101)
  grades = 'high distinction';
else if (scores > 91)
  grades = 'distinction';
else if (scores > 81)
  grades = 'credit';
else if (scores > 71)
  grades = 'pass';
else if (scores > 61)
  grades = 'fail';
else grades = 'none';
document.write('your grade name is' + grades);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally got it. I just do not understand what you meant by adding Number before Prompt for a string problem. Can you also explain it? thank you

Comment: `Number(arg)` will convert the `arg`, whatever its type, into a number. That way, it can be directly compared to other numbers with `>` and `<` without unexpected behavior.

Comment: When answers solve your problem, you can mark them as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add a params when using prompt
try this:
 scores=prompt ('write your score to convert it to grades','');

Answer (score -2):

You need to cast your response into an integer in order tout compare it

Comment: This is one problem, but not the main logical error with the code.

Answer (score -2):

You could simply Google this. It is because your prompt returns a string and not an integer. You need to parse it to a number. Do

```
scores = parseInt(prompt(...));
```